# How to sort and arrange data in many column by pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, sorting

I have large set of data and its arranged in its respective column. How to sort those data and rearrange it horizontally in different column like shown below.

```
day                time             
        12    13   14    15   16
1       0.6   0.5  1.2   1.3  1.5
2       2.1   2    2.5   3    0.5
3       …     …    …     …    ..
```

The original data is like this:

```
date    time    speed
1       12      0.6
1       13      0.5
1       14      1.2
1       15      1.3
1       16      1.5
2       12      2.1
2       13      2
2       14      2.5
2       15      3
2       16      0.5
```

Comment: Use `df.pivot(index='date', columns='time', values='speed')`

Comment: Thanks @Abhi. I imposed  this command  y=df.pivot_table(
    values='speed', index='date', columns='time',   fill_value=0). The result is outstanding!..